# Create variable in one script and use in another script. JQuery/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I turn the results from **Script 1**, `Name, Email, Teams`into variables I can use in **script 2**?

I am making an API call to fetch some JSON I then want to use certain values as text in a message I then send to slack.

**Example.**

```
$('.Name').html(data.user.name); // Returns John
$('.Email').html(data.user.email); // Returns John@John.com
$('.Teams').html(data.user.teams[0].name); // Returns JohnsTeam

var text = 'Hello my name is $Name + my email is $Email + From $Teams'
```

Output = Hello my name is John my email is John@John.com From JohnsTeam

**Script 1**

```
function currentUrl() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
      resolve(tabs[0].url)
    })
  })
}

function userIdfromUrl(url) {
  var parts = url.split('/')
  return parts[parts.length - 1]
}
var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
function myapiRequest(endpoint, options) {
    $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
    $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
    $('.Teams').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
},

    url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
currentUrl()
  .then(function (url) {
    return userIdfromUrl(url)
  })
  .then(function (userId) {
    return myapiRequest('users/' + userId + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams')
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.user.name)
    console.log(data.user.email)
    console.log(data.user.teams[0].name)
  })
```

**Script 2**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-submit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        var text = 'This is a message'
        $.ajax({
            data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
                "text": text // What I want to dynamically change
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: url
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I am not sure what you mean, don't suppose you could provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One great solution is to set the variable you get from the response in the `HTML5 localstorage` as follows:

- Inside ur success:

> ```
> success: function(data) {
>   localStorage.setItem("urdata",JSON.stringify(data));
> }
> ```

- In the other script, u can retrieve the data like this:

> var data = localStorage.getItem("urdata"); data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stay away from any localsotrage. Also I am not sure how each of my returned values would be declared doing it this way. Thanks

Comment: if they're different scripts in different pages, you have whether to use localStorage or a global variable in the session, as far as I know

Comment: Global variable is what I was hoping for, its a chrome application so I think everything is default global.